# .NET 3.5: What is the "ValidatorCollection.IsSynchronized" Property "synchronized" to?

Tags: .net, synchronization, properties

I understand that in .NET 3.5 the

```
ValidatorCollection.IsSynchronized property
```

return a Boolean telling me if it is synchronized or not. However, I'm having a hard time understand **what** is it synchronizing with or to?

The MSDN manual simply says:

> Gets a value that indicates whether the ValidatorCollection collection is synchronized.

which doesn't help much...

Comment: Don't feel bad, this is the most poorly designed (and documented) part of the BCL.

Comment: Yea, no doubt. I guess it does say that. In that little space below. Thanks everyone! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN also says in the remarks :

> If the collection is synchronized, it is thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

It just means that it is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

It's synchronized with itself. You can perform operations on it from different threads, safely.